# grails redirect(action:'index') redirects to show action

Tags: grails, redirect, grails-controller

I'm newbie on grails and I'm trying to write a simple blog application with it. I have some resources and i'm trying to implement a create resource logic.
Here is what i have done;

URL mapping for tags;

```
"/tags"(resources: 'tags')
```

TagsController;

```
class TagsController {
  def index() {
      [tags: Tag.list()]
  }

  def create() { }

  def save() {
      def tag = new Tag(params.tag)
      if(tag.save()) {
          flash.message = "Tag Created Successfully"
          redirect(action: "index")
      }
      else {
          flash.error = "Something went wrong, please check the form again!"
          render(view: "create")
      }
  }

  def show() {
      render "this is the show action"
  }

}
```

With this configurations redirect(action: "index") redirects to tags/index path. But this path is not for index action it is for show action.

What am I doing wrong?

I've tried URL mapping like this;

```
"/tags"(resources: 'tag')
```

In this case tags/ and tags/index paths triggers to index action but tags/6 (6 is an id for existing tag on the database) does not triggers show action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"/tags"(resources: 'tags')` is correct.

If you want to redirect from `save` to `show` you have to provide the `id` required by `show`. See [mapping](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#restfulMappings) how grails maps the urls to actions.

To provide the `id` you can write

```
redirect(action: "index", id: tag.id)
```

or

```
redirect(action: "show", id: tag.id)
```

[Update:]

To redirect to `index` you have to explicitly set the method:

redirect(action: "index", method:"GET")

Comment: I want to redirect index from save.

Comment: it works. Thank you for your updated answer. But it's too weird right? Why do I need to set method? There are no definition about this on the grails documentation. Also are you sure "/tags"(resources: 'tags') is correct? I saw on the documentation they use model name as singular.

Comment: I don't know why we have to provide the method, I didn't find an explanation for it.  It is 'tags' because we map the url on a controller and the controller name is 'TagsController', with 's'. See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#restfulMappings it is the name of the controller.

Comment: As I see at the top of the section they use something like this; "/books"(resources:'book') so they map book resource with /books path right? And in my case i used "/tags"(resources: 'tags'). Is it true or should i use it like "/tags"(resources: 'tag') ? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: resources is just the name of the controller. Usually you would name the controller according to the name of the corresponding domain class. So with domain 'Tag' you name the controller 'TagController'. This makes it easier to see which domain class is handled by a controller. But this is no strict rule. You can name the controller whatever you like.

Comment: You are really helpful. I got it. Thank you :)